# Is there API for setting TLS certificates for Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, gcloud, lets-encrypt

I'd like to automate certification renewal process using Let's Encrypt (implementing ACME challenge answer + converting private key to unencrypted .rsa format).

But the only thing that still requires manual intervention is giving the certificate chain and private key to Google domain manager: 
https://console.cloud.google.com/appengine/settings/certificates
One have to open browser manually and copy-paste certs there.

Is there any possible way I can automate that? Maybe endpoint protected by OAuth2.0 tokens? `gcloud` tool doesn't seem to contain any relevant methods.

Comment: Not yet, but there is an ongoing discussion about it [here](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=12535). Please star the issue to get more attention on it.

Answer (score 2):

You can upload SSL cert to App Engine using `gcloud beta` tools.

```
gcloud beta app ssl-certificates create \
  --display-name mydomain-letsencrypt-aug2017 \
  --certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem \
  --private-key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomain.com/privkey.pem \
  --project hello-app

gcloud beta app domain-mappings update www.mydomain.com \
    --certificate-id $certId \
    --project hello-app
```

https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/google-app-engine/lets-encrypt-on-google-app-engine/